# How I can remove border from table while printing using css @media print

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Hello I try to remove border from my table when the user click button print (window.print) using css but it stay always in printed page

this is my css code  :

```
    @media print{

    body * {visibility: hidden;


    }

    table {
        border:solid; white !important;
        border-width:1px 0 0 1px !important;
        border-bottom-style: none;
    }
    th, td{
        border:solid; white !important;
        border-width:0 1px 1px 0 !important;
        border-bottom-style: none;
    }
}
```

this css gave me this result :

[image]

The bottom border of table stay showing  How do I can remove it Thank u

Comment: First of all, try using `border:solid white !important;` (no `;` after `solid`).

Comment: can you post your html code?

Comment: Try `border-bottom: none;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally This solution worked for me :

```
@media print {

    * {
        color: #000;    
        background-color: #fff;
        @include box-shadow(none);
        @include text-shadow(none);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use in your CSS3 @media Rule:

```
border-bottom: none;
```

or

```
border: solid white !important;
```

Using `border-bottom: none;` could effect the layout of you table when printing (depending if you are using `box-sizing` with default value or not).

Below an example:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        table {
            /* just an example */
            border: solid red;
            border-width: 1px 0 0 1px !important;
            border-bottom-style: none;
        }

        @media print {

            table {
                border: solid white !important;
                border-width: 1px 0 0 1px !important;
                border-bottom-style: none;
            }

            th, td {
                border: solid white !important;
                border-width: 0 1px 1px 0 !important;
                border-bottom-style: none;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```